# Get input and output file size of USQL job programatically

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake, u-sql

In USQL job detail (in UI) I can see that it shows all input and output file names with its size. I want to read this info from C#. I came to know that in adl://bswadls..net/system/jobservice/jobs/Usql/2017/10/29/09/58//query.abr it has that information of file name and streamsize. For input I can see file name and streamsize but for output file I don't see streamsize. In UI they shows this info means it should be there somewhere. Please help me to get size of all output files. I am writing c# tool which will give me all size of input and output files of USQL job.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the C# code inside of U-SQL or in a client side program?

If you want access to the file size inside U-SQL, you currently 
would have to write a custom extractor that reads the `input.baseStream` size for each file. And no, I would not recommend that.

If you want access to the file size inside a client-side application, I would suggest to look at the [ADL C#/.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data-lake-store?view=azure-dotnet).

Comment: No, I don't want file size inside USQL. I want file size from client side application like console application.